# IntelliJ IDEA 12 - Android GUI designer doesn't successfully change app theme

Tags: java, android, user-interface, intellij-idea

The Android GUI designer in IntelliJ has a dropdown for selecting "Framework themes". The problem is, changing it has no effect on what shows up in the emulator when I test my app. No matter what is chosen, the app theme is always the default black Holo theme (Theme.Holo, I'm guessing.) I'd like it to be Theme.Holo.Light - but really it makes no difference which one I select.

Anyone have advice on making this work in the designer?

Answer (score 2):

Theme [needs to be set manually](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyATheme) in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, in the GUI designer this option is used only for previewing how your app will look like with different themes.

Answer (score 0):

"If you want a theme applied to just one Activity in your application, then add the android:theme attribute to the  tag."

e.g.

```
   <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
```

"To set a theme for all the activities of your application, edit the  tag to include the android:theme attribute with the style name"

```
  <application android:theme="@style/CustomTheme">
```

Answer (score 0):

Like CrazyLoader said, you need to change the theme manually in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.For example, if I want to change the theme for all activities in my app to `Holo.Light`, I'll do this:

```
 <application
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light>
```

and if I want the theme to be applied to individual activities, I'll do:

```
<activity
        android:name="MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

Note: If you have your `minSDK` set to anything less than API 11,  you'll get the following error:

> @android:style/Theme.Holo.Light requires API level 11 (current min is 8)